# How do I get last 7 bet slips (BetSlipID) for the certain user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my current code shows bet slips for last 7 days, but I need to show last 7 bet slips regardless of the date.

```
select 
  betsliphistory.MatchID,Team1.Name as HomeTeam ,
  Team2.Name as AwayTeam, BetSlipID , userid , TipID , 
  matches.ResultTipID ,betsliphistory.`Date`
from betsliphistory
inner join matches on betsliphistory.MatchID = matches.MatchID
inner join teams as Team1 on matches.HomeTeamID = Team1.TeamID
inner join teams as Team2 on matches.AwayTeamID = Team2.TeamID
where userid =".$user." 
  and betsliphistory.`Date` between CURDATE()-7 and CURDATE() 
order by BetSlipID , MatchID;
```

Comment: "last 7 bet slips regardless of the date." - if not by date, then what determines the last?

Comment: The last will be the one with the highest betslipID. I solved the problem with Kant's help. Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm only asking because the other answer should provide the correct results while avoiding the sub query. In these cases, a sqlfiddle would really help to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this::

```
 select betsliphistory.MatchID,Team1.Name as HomeTeam , 
                      Team2.Name as AwayTeam, BetSlipID , userid , TipID , matches.ResultTipID ,betsliphistory.`Date`
                      from betsliphistory
                      inner join matches on betsliphistory.MatchID = matches.MatchID
                      inner join teams as Team1 on matches.HomeTeamID = Team1.TeamID
                      inner join teams as Team2 on matches.AwayTeamID = Team2.TeamID
                      inner join (Select DISTINCT(BetSlipID) tempBetSlip from betsliphistory where userid =".$user."  order by `Date` limit 7) temp_betHistory on temp_betHistory.tempBetSlip = BetSlipID
                          where userid =".$user." order by `BetSlipID`
```

Comment: I tried, but it gives me only the last 7 records ,I need all the records for the last 7 betslips.My English is not very good. Sorry about that

Comment: Query returns exactly what I need when I run it in the test database, but when I run it in database used by app, there is empty query. Tables in both databases are same. Thanks for help, i will check what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

> but I need to show last 7 bet slips regardless of the date.

- Remove the date consition from the `WHERE` clause.
- Use `ORDER By BetSlipID DESC` with `LIMIT 7` for the top 7 `BetSlipID`, like so:

  ```
   ... -- Your current query
   WHERE userid = ".$user." 
   ORDER BetSlipID  DESC
   LIMIT 7;
  ```

**Note that:** Your code this way is vulnerable to [**SQL Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use PDO or prepared statement instead. See this for more details:

- [**PHP: Best way to prevent SQL injection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection).